# @Autowired in Spring custom converter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have custom converter:

```
  @Component
public class RoleConverter implements Converter<String, Role> {

    @Autowired private Roles roles;

    @Override
    public Role convert(String id) {
        return roles.findById(Long.parseLong(id));
    }
}
```

But @Autowired is setting null value. Causing `Nullpointerexception`.

This is Roles class:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class Roles extends Domain<Role>{

    public Roles() {
        super(Role.class);
    }

}
```

I'm using Java Configuration. Converter is registered:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
//other annotations...
public class WebappConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
//....


    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new RoleConverter());
        super.addFormatters(registry);
    }


/....

}
```

When I @Autowired Roles in controller its works.

Why @Autowired is setting null in Converter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because here you are creating a new object of `RoleConverter`. Instead you should autowire the `RoleConverter`

Instead of

```
registry.addConverter(new RoleConverter());
```

Use

```
@Autowired
RoleConverter roleConverter;

@Override
public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry)
{
    registry.addConverter(roleConverter);

}
```

Comment: Thanks! You are right. I didn't noticed that. Solved.

Comment: >  Instead you should autowire the RoleConverter

What exactly does this mean?

Comment: life saver, thank you

Comment: Thanks. I was facing the same issue and it rectified with your solution. But can you please elaborate on your solution. Is it because spring's dependency injection will not work if parent classes are invoked using new keyword?